# Differences between this.props.navigation.dispatch vs this.props.navigation.navigate?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I see a lot of folks in the react-navigation issues section using `this.props.navigation.dispatch` to programmatically navigate. Is there any specific reason or use case to use that over `this.props.navigation.navigate`?

It seems like you can pass more options to the dispatch function? Is there anything else? Can you use dispatch without explicitly tying react-navigation into your apps redux store? Right now I have an app that has redux, but I dont explicitly configure my redux setup to know about react-navigation (and would prefer to keep it that way if I can).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the React Navigation docs The Navigation Prop chapter (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop#dispatch-Send-an-action-to-the-router):

> ...The other navigation functions use dispatch behind the scenes...

Also parameters for `NavigationActions.navigate` and `this.props.navigation.navigate` are the same. There should be no difference which one you use. In my opinion, `this.props.navigation.navigate` is shorter and more readable.

Comment: How can I make it work for reactNative? I am using `react-navigation` module, and using Tabbed navigation style. I can not add routes for Add/Edit/Search button in `TabNavigator()` configuraiton (as those are visible main navigation section for user). How can I do screen transition then to may any XX component? I have seen lots of details and its documentation but didn't get any clue, may be its too complex that's why I didn't get it right in my mind.

Comment: link is dead now.

Comment: It's now `CommonActions` instead of `NavigationActions`
--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50781080/navigationactions-reset-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 11):

### From [github](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/23da6aebffcb5677fd3441b4043755350cbee3ed/src/addNavigationHelpers.js#L24,L35) :

[image]

[This is the code](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/23da6aebffcb5677fd3441b4043755350cbee3ed/src/addNavigationHelpers.js#L24,L35) of `navigate` function which reuses `navigation.dispatch`.. And remember:

> Code Don't Lie

Then, `navigation.navigate(...args)` is an alias of `navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate(...args))`

Comment: How can I make it work for reactNative? I am using `react-navigation` module, and using Tabbed navigation style. I can not add routes for Add/Edit/Search button in `TabNavigator()` configuraiton (as those are visible main navigation section for user). How can I do screen transition then to may any XX component? I have seen lots of details and its documentation but didn't get any clue, may be its too complex that's why I didn't get it right in my mind.

Comment: Source code link not available right now. So this is not valid.

Comment: Thank you @AslamHossin ! The link was updated to refer to the commit instead of the branch (master)

Comment: OUTDATED!! It's now `CommonActions` instead of `NavigationActions`
--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50781080/navigationactions-reset-is-not-a-function