# NavigationActions.reset is not a function?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I created a project has a `Welcome` screen navigate to `MainActivity` screen. I want that when the user clicks the back button it will close the app in `MainActivity` not back to `Welcome` screen.  I use the library `react-navigation`, so I looked for some solution from Github.

When I use the code from https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/295. I get the error:

```
NavigationActions.reset is not a function
```

I console.log(NavigationActions);

[image]

There is no reset obviously.  But why can everybody else use the code?

I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my Welcome.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ColorSetting } from './common/ColorSetting';
import { fetchMainMovieList } from '../actions';

class Welcome extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // call main page data first
    this.props.fetchMainMovieList();

    this.timer = setTimeout(() => { 
      this.navigateToMainActivity();
    }, 3000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    // if this.timer existed，then use clearTimeout to remove it.
    this.timer && clearTimeout(this.timer);
  }

  navigateToMainActivity() {
    console.log(NavigationActions);
    const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
      index: 1,
      actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'MainActivity' })
      ]
    });

    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Three !</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { fetchMainMovieList })(Welcome);
```

Comment: which version of react navigation are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined is not a function (evaluating'\_reactNavigation.NavigationActions.reset')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50443451/undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-reactnavigation-navigationactions-reset)

Comment: I use `"react-navigation": "^2.0.4",`

Answer (score 97, accepted):

**Update for V5.x:**

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';


const resetAction = CommonActions.reset({
    index: 1,
    routes: [{ name: YOUR_ROUTE_NAME, params: { YOUR_OPTIONAL_DATA } }]
});
navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

---

in version >2 of react navigation, you can use this code to reset stack:

```
    import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from 'react-navigation';
    const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'MainActivity' })],
        });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

I hope this will help...

Comment: Yes, its the solution. Thank you very much !

Comment: its not working in version 5.x. Try out this link for react-navigation 5 series https://stackoverflow.com/a/67543463/6380514

Answer (score 19):

If you're using a nested router you'll also need to set `key` to null otherwise it'll keep looking into currently active navigator.

```
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from 'react-navigation'
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    key: null, // <-- this
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: route })]
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Even adding key to null, still looking into currently active navigator

Comment: @AnilGhodake all your navigators should be linked under 1 common navigator also. Otherwise there's no way for the library to know

Comment: I have 3 stack navigators linked under a bottom tab navigator, using createBottomTabNavigator. Even when I add `key: null`, it's still looking into the currently active navigator =/

Comment: Me too, added `key: null` but still looking into current navigator, like @kylebebak, mine is nested navigators (SwitchNavigator > DrawerNavigator > BottomTabNavigator, and current StackNavigator).

Comment: I got it to work by setting `key: MyRouteThatHasTargetScreen` and `NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'TargetScreen'})`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
import { CommonActions,useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const navigation = useNavigation();

const resetAction = CommonActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        routes: [{ name: 'MainActivity' }],});
      
       navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

[document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions#reset)

If you're using react-navigation 5.0, you can do it this way

Comment: Can use in react navigation version 6

Answer (score 0):

```
navigateToMainActivity(){
this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset({
  index:0,
  actions:[
    NavigationActions.navigate({routeName:'MainActivity'})
  ] 
   })
  );
 }
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include an explanation of *how* this answers the question. Answers that are little more than a code block are not very useful for those who might come across the same or a similar issue later on.

Comment: It’d also be worth explaining why it might be preferable over the accepted answer from two years ago. From what I can tell it’s the exact same solution with slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In react-navigation v5, you can replace the splash screen with MainActivity Screen like this

`import {StackActions} from '@react-navigation/native'; navigation.dispatch(StackActions.replace('MainActivity'));`