# react native navigation action reset

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a react native app and following is the screen flow-

Splash screen -> login -> FlightList

When I am in flightlist screen, I press back button and it takes me back to splash screen.

I want to exit the app when I press back button in flight screen. I saw some code here 
[NavigationActions.reset is not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50781080/navigationactions-reset-is-not-a-function)

```
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from 'react-navigation'
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    key: null, // <-- this
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: route })]
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

But I am not sure where should I use it. Could any one help me with this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use it anywhere. In your case if you use it in Login your stack will change from **Splashscreen->Login->FlightList** to **FlightList** and i suppose **route** is equal to the name of your **FlighList** in your StackNavigator.

Comment: sorry i dont get u

Comment: I guess you use `NavigationActions.navigate` to go from Login screen to Flight screen but you have to use your resetAction instead.