# How to show loading progress or spinner in the middle of the screen with React Native?

Tags: react-native, animation, loading, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am developing React Native app.

I was able to solve all problems by myself but this is exception.
I am going to load another screen with bottom tab navigator.

For example, after user login to the app, it should show main home screen which has many pictures and many style sheet effects, icons. Because of that, after login confirm ( I mean after alert of the login confirm), the main home screen appears after a few seconds.

So I want to show some spinner in the login screen while loading main home screen in the background and when it is ready to show, erase spinner and show main home screen.
How can I do this?

My bottom tab navigator was simply created with `createBottomTabNavigator()` method.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So in your case you can do several things

1. You can use React Native Activity Indicator -> [View](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator)
2. You can use Overlay Library -> react-native-loading-spinner-overlay -> [View GitHub](https://github.com/joinspontaneous/react-native-loading-spinner-overlay)
3. If you like to make loading like facebook / instagram -> then use react-native-easy-content-loader -> [View GitHub](https://github.com/sarmad1995/react-native-easy-content-loader)

Assume that you are using React Native Activity Indicator :

```js
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  //Get Home Screen Data API Action
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadAPI(); // Call home screen get data API function
  }

  //Login API Function
  loadAPI = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true }); // Once You Call the API Action loading will be true
    fetch(API_URL, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseText => {
        // You can do anything accroding to your API response
        this.setState({ isLoading: false }); // After getting response make loading to false
      })
      .catch(error => {});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        {this.state.isLoading && <ActivityIndicator color={"#fff"} />}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

- If you want to hide all the view until loading finish like images, so you can use custom library instead of Activity Indicator.

Comment: I get great help from you. I still have a question. Can you explain about ```navigation.dispatch```?

Comment: @Yuri Glad to help you ! You can see this thread about dispatch -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43869903/differences-between-this-props-navigation-dispatch-vs-this-props-navigation-navi

Comment: Also refer this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html

Answer (score 5):

I have created my custom Loader component. Using this you can display built in ActivityIndicator or your custom gif loader image with overlay.

**Loader.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Modal,
  Image,
  ActivityIndicator
} from 'react-native';

class Loader extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: this.props.isLoading
    }
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
    return {
      isLoading: nextProps.isLoading
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        transparent={true}
        animationType={'none'}
        visible={this.state.isLoading}
        style={{ zIndex: 1100 }}
        onRequestClose={() => { }}>
        <View style={styles.modalBackground}>
          <View style={styles.activityIndicatorWrapper}>
            <ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.isLoading} color="black" />
            
            {/* If you want to image set source here */}
            {/* <Image
              source={require('../assets/images/loader.gif')}
              style={{ height: 80, width: 80 }}
              resizeMode="contain"
              resizeMethod="resize"
            /> */}
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modalBackground: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    backgroundColor: '#rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
    zIndex: 1000
  },
  activityIndicatorWrapper: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    borderRadius: 10,
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-around'
  }
});

export default Loader
```

Now you can use it when you have to display loading indicator as below :

```js
<Loader isLoading={this.state.isLoading} />
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            spinner : true
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
        <View style={{flex : 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center',}}>
        {
          this.state.spinner &&
          <ActivityIndicator  color={'#fff'} />
        }
        </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what I want to know is that how to set those ```this.state.spinner```. When I have to set it true and when false?

Answer (score 2):

So you can show the SPinner for suppose when you have to load an  API or something and when you get the response of api, you can set spinner loading value to false.

For eg :

```
import {View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

export default class MainScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            spinner : true
        }
    }

componentDidMount(){
this.loadApi();
}

loadApi = async() => {
let result = axios.get('url').then((data) =>{
this.setState({spinner:false});
}
).catch((err) => this.setState({spinner:false})
}

    render() {
        return (
        <View style={{flex : 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center',}}>
        {
          this.state.spinner? <ActivityIndicator  color={'#fff'} />:<View><Text>Data loaded</Text></View>

        }
        </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to use [ActivityIndicator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator)  you can have to load this activityindicator before getting data from the server , you have to check below code hope you will understand

```
    import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, View, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import HomeScreen from './Home';

const DataViewer = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(myJson => {
        setData(myJson);
      });
  });

  return data.length > 0 ? (
    <HomeScreen data={data} />
  ) : (
    <View
      style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height, width}}>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
    </View>
  );
};

export default DataViewer;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Activity indicator as the default loading animation. But you can also use Lottie files to implement custom loading screen animation on your project by installing `npm i lottie-react-native` or `yarn add lottie-react-native`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a simple spinning icon to show progress. You can put it in a view and move it to the center of the page or like in my case put it inside the button to show some activity to the user.

**FontAwesomeSpin.tsx**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Animated, Easing } from 'react-native';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';

interface FontAwesomeSpinProps {
  enabled: boolean;
  color?: string;
  size?: number;
}

class FontAwesomeSpin extends Component<FontAwesomeSpinProps> {
  spinValue = new Animated.Value(0);
  _isMounted = false;

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    if (this.props.enabled) {
      this.spin();
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps: FontAwesomeSpinProps) {
    if (this.props.enabled && !prevProps.enabled) {
      this.spinValue.setValue(0);
      this.spin();
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  spin = () => {
    this.spinValue.setValue(0);

    Animated.timing(this.spinValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 1000,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start(() => {
      if (this._isMounted && this.props.enabled) {
        this.spin();
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { enabled: loading, color, size = 24 } = this.props;

    if (!loading) {
      return null;
    }

    const rotate = this.spinValue.interpolate({ inputRange: [0, 1], outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg'] });

    return (
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          width: size,
          height: size,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          overflow: 'hidden',
          transform: [{ rotate }],
        }}
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon="spinner" color={color} size={size} />
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}

export default FontAwesomeSpin;
```

You can use it like this:

```
 <FontAwesomeSpin enabled={loading} size={32} style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { View, Text, Dimensions, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import LottieView from "lottie-react-native";
import { moderateScale } from 'react-native-size-matters';
export const Loader = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.main}>
<LottieView source={require("../json/Loader.json")} autoPlay loop style={{height:moderateScale(500),width:moderateScale(500)}}  />
    
    </View>
    
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main:{
...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
justifyContent:'center',
alignItems:'center',
flex:1,
backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
```

}
})
export default Loader

Answer (score 0):

Something that might not be mentioned yet is to make custom view component that displays spinner:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View as RNView, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

const View = ({ children, loading, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <RNView {...props}>
      {children}
      {loading && (
        <RNView
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
          }}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="blue" />
        </RNView>
      )}
    </RNView>
  );
};

export default View;
```

This can be used like:

```
<View loading={true}> ... </View>
```